# groupBy array based on combination of 2 properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, lodash

I want to Group array elements based on combination of  2 properties.

I have an array containing `FirstDate` and `LastDate`, where I want to group objects with same combination of `FirstDate` and `LastDate` and create Object with any random unique string as Key OR Array of arrays anything would work.

I have following array,

```js
const data = [ 
    { 
       InvDate: "2021-05-04 00:00:00",
       EntityID: 4309,
       FirstDate: "2021-05-03 18:30:00",
       LastDate: "2021-05-04 18:30:00"
    },
    {  
       InvDate: "2021-05-04 00:00:00",
       EntityID: 4314,
       FirstDate: "2021-05-03 18:30:00",
       LastDate: "2021-05-04 18:30:00"
    },
    {  
       InvDate: "2021-05-04 00:00:00",
       EntityID: 4464,
       FirstDate: "2021-05-01 18:30:00",
       LastDate: "2021-05-04 18:30:00"
    },
    {  
       InvDate: "2021-05-04 00:00:00",
       EntityID: 4465,
       FirstDate: "2021-04-20 18:30:00",
       LastDate: "2021-05-04 18:30:00"
    }
]
```

I want to group object having similar `FirstDate` and `LastDate`, so for example result should look like,

```js
// Array of arrays example
const result1 = [ 
    [
        { 
            InvDate: "2021-05-04 00:00:00",
            EntityID: 4309,
            FirstDate: "2021-05-03 18:30:00",
            LastDate: "2021-05-04 18:30:00"
        },
        {  
            InvDate: "2021-05-04 00:00:00",
            EntityID: 4314,
            FirstDate: "2021-05-03 18:30:00",
            LastDate: "2021-05-04 18:30:00"
        },
    ],
    [
        {  
            InvDate: "2021-05-04 00:00:00",
            EntityID: 4464,
            FirstDate: "2021-05-01 18:30:00",
            LastDate: "2021-05-04 18:30:00"
        },
    ],
    [
        {  
            InvDate: "2021-05-04 00:00:00",
            EntityID: 4465,
            FirstDate: "2021-04-20 18:30:00",
            LastDate: "2021-05-04 18:30:00"
        }
    ]
]
```

OR

```js
// GroupedBy object with any random key example
const result2 = { 
    "random1": [
        { 
            InvDate: "2021-05-04 00:00:00",
            EntityID: 4309,
            FirstDate: "2021-05-03 18:30:00",
            LastDate: "2021-05-04 18:30:00"
        },
        {  
            InvDate: "2021-05-04 00:00:00",
            EntityID: 4314,
            FirstDate: "2021-05-03 18:30:00",
            LastDate: "2021-05-04 18:30:00"
        },
    ],
    "random2": [
        {  
            InvDate: "2021-05-04 00:00:00",
            EntityID: 4464,
            FirstDate: "2021-05-01 18:30:00",
            LastDate: "2021-05-04 18:30:00"
        },
    ],
    "random3": [
        {  
            InvDate: "2021-05-04 00:00:00",
            EntityID: 4465,
            FirstDate: "2021-04-20 18:30:00",
            LastDate: "2021-05-04 18:30:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

It's in node, doesn't have to be in VaniallaJS, use of **Lodash** function would work, as I already have it installed in my app.

Comment: for lodash https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy might come in handy

Comment: @georg Yeah, by using that I was able to group using single key like `LastDate`, but m not sure how do I group using a combination of keys

Comment: in this particular case, you can simply concatenate them: `_.groupBy(data, x => x.FirstDate + x.LastDate)`

Comment: That does work @georg, I'll also test with my exact data and can you explain in comments or in answer, how does concatenating them groups them, for me and entire stack audience for future references.

Comment: I almost understood what it is doing but, if u could explain, that would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With lodash [`groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy) you can use a callback ("iteratee") to create a compound key to group by two fields at once. In your example this is easy, because all dates have the same format, so you can simply concatenate (add) them to create unique compound keys. That is,

```
_.groupBy(data, item => item.FirstDate + item.LastDate)
```

should do what you want.

In the general case, where keys can be arbitrary strings or even other types, you can use JSON to combine them into a single string key, for example:

```
_.groupBy(data, item => JSON.stringify([item.firstKey, item.secondKey]))
```